# Unable to send data to view in nodejs app

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

Pardon my novice question. Learning how to build node.js apps with mysql and ejs. My challenge is I'm not able to get a hang on how data retrieved from my database will be sent in my response and displayed. In the past 2 days i have tried different ways to do it to the best of my understanding from answer here but have failed. This is the code I'm playing with and need help on

```
//index.js

router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1', function(err, row) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        var user = row;

        res.render('home', {
            title: 'Home',
            data: user
        });
    }
});
});


//home.ejs
<p class="text-center pb-2">Hello <%= user.name %></p>
```

When i run my app.js file i get 500 response and user is not defined error message.

Comment: Well you define a key 'data' in your render function, so I wouldn't see how in the template then all of a sudden a key 'user' would be available.

Comment: @Gimby changed `user.name` to `data.name` inside home.ejs, page renders well but no name is displayed. Instead i get Hello, but what i want is say Hello world. Any more tips on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
router.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1', function(err, row) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        var user = row;
        res.render('home', {
            title: 'Home',
            user: user
        });
        }
    });
});
```

You didnt send an user object to the ejs engine, you sent the user object inside the `data` property.

---

Or, in the other way around, in your `home.ejs` file, you can write:

```
<p class="text-center pb-2">Hello <%= data.user.name %></p>
```

Comment: I have edited my code and able to display the page but the name is not displayed. I can see the data when i do `res.send(user)` so why is it not displayed in my view when i do `user.name`

Comment: @Mena Can you please do `console.dir(row)` snd post the result here so i can see how your `user` object is built?

Comment: `[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    name: 'marcus',
    email: 'marcus@mail.com',
    password: 'password' } ]`

Comment: @Mena Ok,thanks,  now please update your original question, so it will be more clear what is the current situation in your code. there are a lot of not clear options in your current description

Comment: My question actually says the challenge is displaying the data on the view page. So on my home.ejs, i want to be able to display the name from the return data so my paragraph reads "Hello macus".